# Next JS Use query parameter as variable in rewrite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Using Next JS I want to redirect requests on path `/home?id=123qwert` to the new destination path of `/home/123qwert`

I'm having issues with extracting the query parameter from the source to be used again in the destination.

Here is my current implementation:

```
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            /**
             * My source URL -> /home?id=123qwerty
             * My new destination -> /home/123qwerty
             */
            {
                source: '/home?id=:cmsId*',
                destination: '/home/:cmsId*'
            }
        ];
    }
```

I have a dynamic page setup for home as `/home/[id].js`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Reason: Unexpected MODIFIER at 5, expected END

  /home?id=:cmsId*
       ^

`source` parse failed for route {"source":"/home?id=:cmsId*","destination":"/home/:cmsId*"}
```

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your implementation, can you provide a reproduction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [query matching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#header-cookie-and-query-matching) using the `has` field to match a rewrite by query values, with the `beforeFiles` syntax so the match happens before the filesystem check.

```js
async rewrites() {
    return {
        beforeFiles: [
            {
                 source: '/home',
                 has: [
                     {
                         type: 'query',
                         key: 'id',
                         value: '(?<cmsId>.*)' // Named capture group to match anything on the value
                     }
                 ],
                 destination: '/home/:cmsId'
             }
         ]
    };
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. If you have source of `/home?id=test` destination becomes `/home/id=test`. In other words it does not understand variables, it understands only subpaths

Comment: @MarcoFiocco You were right, my solution wasn't working properly. I've updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: @juliomalves Do you know how to allow other query params to be passed through with your solution? i.e. `/home?id=test&foo=bar` would go to destination `/home/test?foo=bar`. Right now, that rewrite doesn't match anything with additional query params.

Comment: What would be the desired destination given `/home?id=test&foo=bar`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It was my mistake, the query string wasn't formatted correctly. The above solution does match other query params.